# def extract_features(list_images) ....Gives: NameError: name 'image' is not defined

Tags: python, tensorflow

This code is producing this error:

> NameError: name 'image' is not defined

I would appreciate any help:

```
  def extract_features(list_images):
       nb_features = 2048
       features = np.empty((len(list_images),nb_features))
       labels = []

       create_graph()

       with tf.Session() as sess:
          next_to_last_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')

    for ind, image in enumerate(list_images):
        if (ind%100 == 0):
             print('Processing %s...' % (image))
    if not gfile.Exists(image):
        tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)

    image_data = gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb').read()
    predictions = sess.run(next_to_last_tensor,
    {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
    features[ind,:] = np.squeeze(predictions)
    labels.append(re.split('_\d+',image.split('/')[1])[0])

    return features, labels
```

In a previous section of the code I declare this:

```
list_images = [images_dir+f for f in os.listdir(images_dir) if   re.search('jpg|JPG', f)]
```

Comment: you only define image inside the for loop. In case that list_images is empty it is actually never defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have indentation bug, you need to add another tab to

```
  if not gfile.Exists(image):
        tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', image)
```

lines.

The issue: image is defined just if `list_images` if a iterable with at least one value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer above. It worked by redefining the images_dir.